# Using vimeo video and images in one fancybox pop-up

Tags: jquery, video, image-gallery, vimeo, fancybox-2

```
<section id="smoking-full">

  <a class="various" data-fancybox-group="group5" title="" data-fancybox-type="iframe"       href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/56039083">
  <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group4" title="" href="Images/cue/design/2.png">

  <img src="Images/smoking/smoking_full.jpg" alt="2" class="image_full"/></a>

</section>
```

I've given each item it's own fancy-box class, but is there anyway to combine them so the pop-up has both items in the carousel?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you read the FAQ? Basically, post code you have tried

Answer (score 3):

Basically all your anchors have to share the same `class` AND the same `data-fancybox-group` to be within the same gallery. Then each may have a different `data-fancybox-type` to differentiate the `type` of content.

so the html :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group01" title="" data-fancybox-type="image"  href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">open image in gallery</a>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group01" title="" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/56039083">open video in gallery</a>
```

Since the fancybox's gallery navigation buttons may block some of the video controls, you may prefer to move them outside of the content (for `iframe` only) with css :

```
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav {
    width: 60px;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-next {
    right: -60px;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
```

And then you can use this script for your gallery

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // solves some issues with streamed media
    iframe: {
        preload: false
    },
    // Increase left/right margin for iframe content
    margin: [20, 60, 20, 60]
});
```

**Notice** the API options that I am recommending to set to avoid further issues.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kv5pw/)**